# Android didn't find application class crash

Tags: android

In Manifest I declared

```
<application
    android:name=com.example.App>
```

When the app starts, sometimes this crash happens:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.example.myapp-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.example.myapp-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4514)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1381)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is it possible to fix it somehow?

Comment: Have you created Application class?

Comment: "sometimes this crash happens": can you elaborate on that? When does it crash, after a reinstall?

Comment: Yes, I have created Application class. This crash seems to happen on end user devices. I don't know exactly when it happens.

Comment: I have the same issue! Sometimes it is crashing on enduser devices 1 out of 10 times. Any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seems to be an app crash. This is just a verbose message raised when dalvik reinstall the apk.It won't occur on end-user's device.To fix it on your development machine, just clean and rebuild.

Comment: I see this crash in the Developer Console. It also shows on which devices it occured.